# which Centos base environment installation is required for Hadoop instatllation

Tags: hadoop, centos7

I am installing Centos for learning Hadoop. But want to know while installing Centos which Base Environment I need to select while installing Centos

https://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/11/step-by-step-centos-7-64-bit.html

Comment: do you want to install centos on your VM or on the bare metal?

Comment: You definitely don't need a GUI to install Hadoop, so "base environment" would be a recent Centos version that has SSH enabled... For example, start with learning within a Vagrant VM rather than just learning how to install the OS (because most of the time at companies, that's already automated for you)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed? If not try downloading centos image directly and spin up a VM.
If you are using vmbox - try below
https://www.osboxes.org/centos/